# Finding Big-O of this code

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I need some help finding the complexity or Big-O of this code. If someone could explain what the Big-O of every loop would be that would be great. I think the outter loop would just be O(n) but the inner loop I'm not sure, how does the *=2 effect it?

```
k = 1;

do
{
   j = 1;
   do
   {
      ...
      j *= 2;
   } while (j < n);

   k++;
} while (k < n);
```

Answer (score 4):

The outer loop runs O(n) times, since k starts at 1 and needs to be incremented n-1 times to become equal to 1.

The inner loop runs O(lg(n)) times. This is because on the m-th execcution of the loop, j = 0.5 * 2^(m).

The loop breaks when n = j = 0.5 * 2^m. Rearranging that, we get m = lg(2n) = O(lg(n)).

Putting the two loops together, the total code complexity is O(nlg(n)).

Logarithms can be tricky, but generally, whenever you see something being repeatedly being multiplied or divided by a constant factor, you can guess that the complexity of your algorithm involves a term that is either logarithmic or exponential.

That's why [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which repeatedly divides the size of the list it searches in half, is also O(lg(n)).

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop always runs from `j=1` to `j=n`.

For simplicity, let's assume that `n` is a power of 2 and that the inner loop runs `k` times.

The values of `j` for each of the `k` iterations are,

```
j = 1
j = 2
j = 4
j = 8
.... 
j = n
// breaks from the loop
```

which means that `2^k = n` or `k = lg(n)`

So, each time, it runs for `O(lg(n))` times.

Now, the outer loop is executed `O(n)` times, starting from `k=1` to `k=n`.

Therefore, every time `k` is incremented, the inner loop runs `O(lg(n))` times.

```
k=1 Innerloop runs for : lg(n)
k=2 Innerloop runs for : lg(n)
k=3 Innerloop runs for : lg(n)
...
k=n Innerloop runs for : lg(n)
// breaks from the loop
```

Therefore, total time taken is `n*lg(n)`

Thus, the time complexity of this is `O(nlg(n))`